# Bluetooth headset gives error connection failed: blueman.bluez.errors.dbusfailederror: protocol not available

Tags: bluetooth, ubuntu-gnome, headset

Everything works with Nokia BH-604. Jaybird X2 connects and after a few seconds disconnects. Both headsets work with Windows 8.1 in the same computer (dual boot). Using blueman-manager 2.0.4 I get the error in topic. How do I get Jaybird X2 to work with Ubuntu Gnome 16.04?

Comment: same problem here. I have a fresh xubuntu 16.04 installation on my dell latitude e6410 laptop. Trying to connect to JBL Charge3 speaker. The device was paired, but i can connect only to serial port. When Try to connect to audio sink or headset I get Connection Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError: Protocol not available

Comment: Did you solve it?

Comment: Not yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a new laptop, plugged in the harddisk from the non-working-bluetooth-laptop and everything worked. So this is most likely a hardware version problem, i.e. Jaybird bluetooth does not support older bluetooth hardware.

Answer (score 4):

This solution worked for me: https://zach-adams.com/2014/07/bluetooth-audio-sink-stream-setup-failed/

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

Delete the device from bluetooth devices and pair it again.

Comment: I get "Failure: Module initialization failed"